# Help identify a strange root vegetable

Tags: vegetables, food-identification

The other day I ventured into a grocery store that sold a lot of root vegetables that I have never seen before.

One of the vegetables was a large round thing, and when I poked it, grey 'smoke' came out of it, like one of those mushrooms you stepped on as a kid. None of the vegetables were labeled, so I don't know its name.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists, and what does one do with it?

Comment: Could you go back and take a picture of it?

Comment: Could you give us a more detailed description than 'a large round thing'. What colour was it? How large is 'large'? Was it rough or smooth etc.

Comment: it was brown, it looked like a turnip that was brown, and about 2x larger then a turnip would look

Comment: I'm afraid I can't offer any further suggestions, but it would probably just be easier to ask somebody who works at the grocery store? Make sure you let us know what it is, I'm curious.

Comment: I have to agree with nixy's answer, why don't you just go into the grocery store and ask customer service?  Without a picture I think it's very unlikely you're going to get an answer here.  It would only take 5 minutes next time you're in the grocery store to get an answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: Did you ever find out what the mystery vegetable was?

Comment: no - but i plan on going back there some day and taking a picture. ill post back here once i do

Comment: Including where in the world this grocery store was located might also help.

Comment: I like how you decided to poke the unidentified thing ^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure it was not in fact a puffball fungus?  There are some varieties that are edible and can be found in grocery stores.  Depending on how fresh, and when they were picked, they could easily be mistaken for a root vegetable.  Look for pear shaped puffball here for an example. http://www.wildernesscollege.com/edible-wild-mushrooms.html

Comment: Might be worth looking on [google images at puffball mushrooms](http://www.google.co.uk/images?q=puffball+mushrooms), as they come in many varieties.

Comment: Don't pick these fugus from your yard, they might be of non-edible type or even be poisonous - unless you are a TRUE expert.